# Tikz spy - empty zoom with pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, spy

I have issues getting the `spy` library to work on my current installation. I am running TeXmaker with MikTeX 2.9 (with all packages updated) on Win8.1x64.

I read about the issues others are having with this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/no-content-in-zoom-tikz-spy) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33260/tikz-example-involving-spies-wont-typeset-properly-using-xelatex), but I still don't get it to work using PdfLaTeX with direct pdf output.

This is the MWE I am using:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Using Wikipedia's image of the day
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{Coiled_Galaxy.jpg}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)},
                  spy using outlines={red,circle,magnification=4, size=3cm,connect spies}]

%       \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%       \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \spy on (0.70,0.95) in node  at (0.5,1.2);
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
Pgf Version: \pgfversion

\end{document}

% Log 
% This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.29)
```

And this is my result:

[image: MWE_output]

**EDIT:** 
My mistake was as Ulrike Fischer pointed out, there was no image for spy to work with, nothing to do with my packages.

The fixed solution is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ spy using outlines={red,circle,magnification=4, size=3cm,connect spies}]
    % Use Wikipedias image of the day
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{Coiled_Galaxy.jpg}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]

        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \end{scope}
    \spy on ($0.95*(image.south east)+0.95*(image.north west)$) in node at ([yshift=1cm]image.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
Pgf Version: \pgfversion

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image: Fixed example]

Comment: Your image must be inside the scope.

Comment: How would one then get the spy to scale with the image then? The principle I am working on here, is based on [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can always do calculations with the node coordinates, e..g. `\spy on ($0.5*(image.south)+0.5*(image.center)$) in node  at ([yshift=1cm]image.north); `

Comment: Ah, makes sense! It's fixed now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure I've seen something very similar to this answer somewhere else, but I can't find it. But anyway, here is an `image` coordinate system which provides a way to refer to coordinates in the image (actually the node containing the image which should have zero `innersep` and `outersep`) using both relative coordinates (from `0` to `1`) and exact coordinates (i.e., with units).

In this example I have used `universe.jpg` from the [lecturer](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/lecturer) package. The `image cs` will not produce great results if you do something "clever" like rotate or slant the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{image}{%
  \tikzset{image cs/.cd, #1}%
    \pgfpointdiff%
      {\pgfpointanchor{\graphicname}{south west}}%
      {\pgfpointanchor{\graphicname}{north east}}%
    \pgfgetlastxy\graphicwidth\graphicheight%
    \pgfmathparse{\graphicx}%
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\def\graphicwidth{1}\fi%
    \pgfmathparse{\graphicy}%
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\def\graphicheight{1}\fi%
    \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\graphicname}{south west}}%
      {\pgfpoint{(\graphicx)*\graphicwidth}{(\graphicy)*\graphicheight}}%
}
\tikzset{image cs/.cd,
  x/.store in=\graphicx, y/.store in=\graphicy,
  image/.store in=\graphicname
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={white, ultra thick, 
  circle, magnification=4, size=3cm, connect spies}]
  \node  [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (universe) 
    {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{universe.jpg}};
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}{ 
  \node [below] at (image cs:image=universe, x=\x/10, y=0) {0.\x};
  \node [above] at (image cs:image=universe, x=\x cm, y=1) {\x cm};
}
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9}{
  \node [left]  at (image cs:image=universe, x=0, y=\y/10) {0.\y};
  \node [right] at (image cs:image=universe, x=1, y=\y cm) {\y cm};
}

\spy on (image cs:image=universe, x=0.69, y=0.88) in node at (-2, 5);
\spy on (image cs:image=universe, x=5cm,  y=5cm)  in node at (-5, 0);
\spy on (image cs:image=universe, x=0.41, y=0.12) in node at ( 5,-5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]